Where is my mistake of calculate the area of part of sphere
For a sphere $S_r=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2  =r^2\}$. Denote the north pole $(0,0,1)$ as $N$.  Consider the set
$$
H_\rho=\{p\in S_r: d(p,N)\le \rho\}
$$
where  $d$ is the spherical distance. I try to calculate the area of $H_\rho$.
For $\theta\in [0,2\pi], \varphi\in [0,\rho/r]$, consider
$$
f(\theta,\varphi) = (r\sin \varphi\cos\theta, r\sin\varphi\sin \theta, r\cos\varphi)
$$
Obviously, the image of $f$ is $H_\rho$. Then,
$$
f_\theta=(-r \sin\varphi\sin\theta, r\sin\varphi\cos\theta, 0)  \\
f_\varphi=(r \cos\varphi\cos\theta, r\cos\varphi\sin\theta, -r\sin\varphi)
$$
Therefore, the Riemannian metric is
$$
g_{\theta\theta} =r^2 (\sin\varphi)^2
~~~~~~
g_{\varphi\varphi}= r^2 (\cos\varphi)^2
$$
So, $\sqrt{|g|}=r^2 \sin\varphi\cos\varphi$. So, the area of $H_\rho$ is
$$
|H_\rho| =\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\rho/r} r^2 \sin\varphi\cos\varphi  d\varphi d\theta
=
\pi r^2 (\sin(\rho/r))^2
\tag{1}
$$
When $\rho=\frac{\pi r}{2}$, $H_\rho$ is semi-sphere, its area is $2\pi r^2$. But the (1) is $\pi r^2$. Where is my mistake?

Schematic diagram. Forgive me  draw  ugly.



Check the inner product for $g_{\phi\phi}$.

@DavidK  Thanks,
